# Split dataframe into multiple dataframes based on both groupby and binning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, binning

I have a dataframe in pandas containing information that I would like sort into groups based on their id ('square'). I want to obtain the mean brightness for each group, and based on this mean brightness I want to bin the dataframe into 4 categories, and get 4 output dataframes.

Example dataframe:

```
squares = pd.DataFrame({'square': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 6.0, 6: 7.0, 7: 8.0},
                    'time': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 3.0, 5: 3.0, 6: 4.0, 7: 5.0 },
                    'x': {0: 243, 1: 293, 2: 189, 3: 189, 4: 176, 5: 374, 6: 111, 7: 239},
                    'y': {0: 233, 1: 436, 2: 230, 3: 233, 4: 203, 5: 394, 6: 171, 7: 284}, 
                    'brightness': {0: 1000, 1: 1200, 2: 4000, 3: 5000, 4: 2000, 5: 8000, 6: 1300, 7: 4300 }})

squares = squares.set_index('time')
squares


      brightness     square     x     y 
time
1.0     1000          1.0       243   233
2.0     1200          1.0       293   436
1.0     4000          2.0       189   230
2.0     5000          2.0       189   233
3.0     2000          5.0       176   203
3.0     6000          6.0       374   394 
4.0     1300          7.0       111   171
5.0     4300          8.0       239   284
```

Desired end result:

```
squares_1

      brightness     square     x     y 
time
1.0     1000          1.0       243   233
2.0     1200          1.0       293   436
3.0     2000          5.0       176   203
4.0     1300          7.0       111   171


squares_2

NaN


squares_3

      brightness     square     x     y 
time
1.0     4000          2.0       189   230
2.0     5000          2.0       189   233
5.0     4300          8.0       239   284


squares_4

      brightness     square     x     y 
time
3.0     6000          6.0       374   394
```

I've started out with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

avg = squares.groupby('square')['brightness'].mean()
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(avg, bins = 4)
inds = np.digitize(avg, bins)
```

I'm not quite sure how to continue though. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` for new `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`, then binning by [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) and last create `dictionary of DataFrame`s:

```
squares = squares.set_index('time')

labs = [f'squares_{x+1}' for x in range(4)]
g = pd.cut(squares.groupby('square')['brightness'].transform('mean'), bins=4, labels=labs)
print (g)
time
1.0    squares_1
2.0    squares_1
1.0    squares_2
2.0    squares_2
3.0    squares_1
3.0    squares_4
4.0    squares_1
5.0    squares_2
Name: brightness, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [squares_1 < squares_2 < squares_3 < squares_4]

dfs = dict(tuple(squares.groupby(g)))
```

---

```
print (dfs)
{'squares_1':       square    x    y  brightness
time                              
1.0      1.0  243  233        1000
2.0      1.0  293  436        1200
3.0      5.0  176  203        2000
4.0      7.0  111  171        1300, 'squares_2':       square    x    y  brightness
time                              
1.0      2.0  189  230        4000
2.0      2.0  189  233        5000
5.0      8.0  239  284        4300, 'squares_3': Empty DataFrame
Columns: [square, x, y, brightness]
Index: [], 'squares_4':       square    x    y  brightness
time                              
3.0      6.0  374  394        8000}
```

---

```
print (dfs['squares_1'])
      square    x    y  brightness
time                              
1.0      1.0  243  233        1000
2.0      1.0  293  436        1200
3.0      5.0  176  203        2000
4.0      7.0  111  171        1300

print (dfs['squares_2'])
      square    x    y  brightness
time                              
1.0      2.0  189  230        4000
2.0      2.0  189  233        5000
5.0      8.0  239  284        4300

print (dfs['squares_3'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [square, x, y, brightness]
Index: []

print (dfs['squares_4'])
      square    x    y  brightness
time                              
3.0      6.0  374  394        8000
```

Comment: I get an error after using the transform command: "Categorical categories must be unique" :(

Comment: If use `plt.hist(avg, bins = 4)` there is no problem?

Comment: @UserR6 - Myu main problem is I cannot simulate your error.